# reverse order in R leaflet continuous legend

Tags: r, leaflet, legend

I am trying to reverse the value display of my `leaflet` legend in R. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413586/r-leaflet-legend-specify-order-instead-of-alphabetical) covers categorical data, but I am working with continuous data. Here's a toy example:

```
map <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldTopoMap')
x <- 1:100
pal <- colorNumeric(c("#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf","#abd9e9", "#2c7bb6"), x)
map %>% addLegend('topright', pal=pal, values=x)
```

I'd like the legend to read 100 at the top and 1 on the bottom with the colors reversed. I can certainly reverse the colors in `colorNumeric()`, but reversing the order of the labels is harder. I have tried reversing the order of the values in `x`, and I even fiddled with the `labelFormat()` parameter for `addLegend()` to reference a lookup table of reversed values... nothing seems to work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately the accepted answer to this will get the numbers out of alignment (in fact exactly reversed) from the colours they represent.

Here's the original proposed solution, which I say is incorrect:

```
map <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldTopoMap')
x <- 1:100
pal <- colorNumeric(c("#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf","#abd9e9", "#2c7bb6"), x)
map %>% addLegend('topright', pal=pal, values=x)

# This solution shows 100 as red
map %>% addLegend('topright',
                  pal = pal, 
                  values = x, 
                  labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))
```

[image]

But if you've been using the `pal()` function to draw anything on your map, you now have it exactly wrong.

```
# But 100 is blue, not red
plot(1, 1, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = pal(100))
```

[image]

I think the solution is to define to functions that allocate colours to numbers, one in reverse for the legend, and one for actually drawing things:

```
pal_rev <- colorNumeric(c("#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf","#abd9e9", "#2c7bb6"), x, reverse = TRUE)

map %>% addLegend('topright',
                  pal = pal_rev, 
                  values = x, 
                  labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))
```

This gives us a legend that matches anything we will have drawn ie 100 is now correctly shown to be blue:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Although the accepted answer does flip the legend's colors and labels, the map's colors do not adress to the legend. Here is a (stolen from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/256#issuecomment-440290201)) solution. Basically [mpriem89](https://github.com/mpriem89) created a new function called `addLegend_decreasing` which works exactly like `addLegend` with an extra argument: `decreasing = FALSE` that reverses the legend's colors and labels, correctly adressing to the map's colors. Here is the function code:

```r
    addLegend_decreasing <- function (map, position = c("topright", "bottomright", "bottomleft","topleft"),
                                  pal, values, na.label = "NA", bins = 7, colors, 
                                  opacity = 0.5, labels = NULL, labFormat = labelFormat(), 
                                  title = NULL, className = "info legend", layerId = NULL, 
                                  group = NULL, data = getMapData(map), decreasing = FALSE) {
  
        position <- match.arg(position)
        type <- "unknown"
        na.color <- NULL
        extra <- NULL
        if (!missing(pal)) {
            if (!missing(colors)) 
                stop("You must provide either 'pal' or 'colors' (not both)")
            if (missing(title) && inherits(values, "formula")) 
                title <- deparse(values[[2]])
            values <- evalFormula(values, data)
            type <- attr(pal, "colorType", exact = TRUE)
            args <- attr(pal, "colorArgs", exact = TRUE)
            na.color <- args$na.color
            if (!is.null(na.color) && col2rgb(na.color, alpha = TRUE)[[4]] == 
                    0) {
                na.color <- NULL
            }
            if (type != "numeric" && !missing(bins)) 
                warning("'bins' is ignored because the palette type is not numeric")
            if (type == "numeric") {
                cuts <- if (length(bins) == 1) 
                    pretty(values, bins)
                else bins   
                if (length(bins) > 2) 
                    if (!all(abs(diff(bins, differences = 2)) <= 
                                     sqrt(.Machine$double.eps))) 
                        stop("The vector of breaks 'bins' must be equally spaced")
                n <- length(cuts)
                r <- range(values, na.rm = TRUE)
                cuts <- cuts[cuts >= r[1] & cuts <= r[2]]
                n <- length(cuts)
                p <- (cuts - r[1])/(r[2] - r[1])
                extra <- list(p_1 = p[1], p_n = p[n])
                p <- c("", paste0(100 * p, "%"), "")
                if (decreasing == TRUE){
                    colors <- pal(rev(c(r[1], cuts, r[2])))
                    labels <- rev(labFormat(type = "numeric", cuts))
                }else{
                    colors <- pal(c(r[1], cuts, r[2]))
                    labels <- rev(labFormat(type = "numeric", cuts))
                }
                colors <- paste(colors, p, sep = " ", collapse = ", ")
            }
            else if (type == "bin") {
                cuts <- args$bins
                n <- length(cuts)
                mids <- (cuts[-1] + cuts[-n])/2
                if (decreasing == TRUE){
                    colors <- pal(rev(mids))
                    labels <- rev(labFormat(type = "bin", cuts))
                }else{
                    colors <- pal(mids)
                    labels <- labFormat(type = "bin", cuts)
                }
            }
            else if (type == "quantile") {
                p <- args$probs
                n <- length(p)
                cuts <- quantile(values, probs = p, na.rm = TRUE)
                mids <- quantile(values, probs = (p[-1] + p[-n])/2, na.rm = TRUE)
                if (decreasing == TRUE){
                    colors <- pal(rev(mids))
                    labels <- rev(labFormat(type = "quantile", cuts, p))
                }else{
                    colors <- pal(mids)
                    labels <- labFormat(type = "quantile", cuts, p)
                }
            }
            else if (type == "factor") {
                v <- sort(unique(na.omit(values)))
                colors <- pal(v)
                labels <- labFormat(type = "factor", v)
                if (decreasing == TRUE){
                    colors <- pal(rev(v))
                    labels <- rev(labFormat(type = "factor", v))
                }else{
                    colors <- pal(v)
                    labels <- labFormat(type = "factor", v)
                }
            }
            else stop("Palette function not supported")
            if (!any(is.na(values))) 
                na.color <- NULL
        }
        else {
            if (length(colors) != length(labels)) 
                stop("'colors' and 'labels' must be of the same length")
        }
        legend <- list(colors = I(unname(colors)), labels = I(unname(labels)), 
                                     na_color = na.color, na_label = na.label, opacity = opacity, 
                                     position = position, type = type, title = title, extra = extra, 
                                     layerId = layerId, className = className, group = group)
        invokeMethod(map, data, "addLegend", legend)
        }
```

Once you've run it, you should replace `addLegend` with `addLegend_decreasing` and set `decreasing = TRUE`. Then, your code changes to:

```r
    #Default map:
    map <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldTopoMap')
    x <- 1:100
    pal <- colorNumeric(c("#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf","#abd9e9", "#2c7bb6"), x)
    map %>% addLegend_decreasing('topright', pal = pal, values = x, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Here is an example for a real `leaflet` map:

```r
    df <- local({
    n <- 300; x <- rnorm(n); y <- rnorm(n)
    z <- sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2); z[sample(n, 10)] <- NA
    data.frame(x, y, z)
    })
    pal <- colorNumeric("OrRd", df$z)
    leaflet(df) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z), group = "circles") %>%
          addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~z, group = "circles", position = "bottomleft") %>%
            addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("circles"))
```

Map with default addLegend:

[image]

Same map with `addLegend_decreasing` and `decreasing = TRUE`

```r
    leaflet(df) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z), group = "circles") %>%
          addLegend_decreasing(pal = pal, values = ~z, group = "circles", position = "bottomleft", decreasing = TRUE) %>%
            addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("circles"))
```

Map with custom addLegend_decreasing:

[image]

Hope this helps, it certainly helped me.

Comment: Great job, this was driving me mad. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 6):

I just found that the built-in `labelFormat` function has a `transform` parameter that takes a function. So I passed the `sort` function in there.
To use the same example,

```
map %>% addLegend('topright',
              pal = pal, 
              values = x, 
              labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken the legend that comes out of this has reversed the labels but not the colours, so it is exactly long. You can check this with `plot(1:10, 1:10, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = pal(100))` which shows that x=100 is turning up as blue, although the legend says it is red.