# Update to "reverse order in R leaflet continuous legend"?

Tags: r, leaflet, legend, choropleth

I have exactly the same question as this one from 5 years ago. I want to invert the scale of a continuous color scale in a leaflet choropleth created from R. I'm hoping that there is a better answer available now, than then.

[reverse order in R leaflet continuous legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276569/reverse-order-in-r-leaflet-continuous-legend)

Here is my code:
(dput()ed data available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1asaNqvtm0VXGH-o7GoWVd3Q6FSm1RNES/view )

```
pal <- colorNumeric("magma", NULL)

map.positivity.leaflet <-
    leaflet(data=D) %>%
    setView(lng=-72.8, lat=41.5, zoom=9) %>%
    addPolygons(color="lightgrey",      # stroke color
                stroke = TRUE,
                weight = 1.5,           # stroke
                fillColor = ~pal(town.positivity),
                fillOpacity = 1,
                label = ~text,
                labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "15px", ## could also set "font-size" in 'style' arg
                                            style = list( # add custom CSS
                                                "background-color" = "darkgreen",
                                                "color" = "white" # font color
                                            ))) %>%
    addLegend(
        "bottomright",
        pal = pal,
        values = ~town.positivity,
        title = "<b>Test Positivity (%)</b>",
        opacity = 1
    )
```

Here is what I get:

[image: choropleth with inverted colorscale]

I want the colorscale to run from 0 at the bottom to its maximum at the top. Is there a less kludgy way to do that than available in answers to the 5 year old question cited above?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput()`?

Comment: @quinten the data is too big to include on so. Here is the dput()ed data on google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1asaNqvtm0VXGH-o7GoWVd3Q6FSm1RNES/view?usp=sharing . Or, see complete code and data here: https://github.com/davebraze/ct-covid-map-examples/ . See especially the file https://github.com/davebraze/ct-covid-map-examples/blob/master/ct-covid-map.R

Comment: Have you tried adding:  labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)) to addLegend()?

Comment: Hi @SusanSwitzer, thank you for weighing in. Your suggestion does have the effect of reversing the labels, but since it does not change the actual mapping from colors to values, that means that the colorscale is not just "upside down", but it is now also incorrect. This is detailed in the 5 year old question that I cited in my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
you need two palettes (pal and pla_2).
pal_2 are reverse for the legende
And you need this code for reverse the order in the addLedgend : labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x)  sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)

```
pal <- colorNumeric("magma", NULL)
pal_2< colorNumeric("magma", NULL, reverse = TRUE)
map.positivity.leaflet <-
   leaflet(data=D) %>%
   setView(lng=-72.8, lat=41.5, zoom=9) %>%
   addPolygons(color="lightgrey",      # stroke color
          stroke = TRUE,
          weight = 1.5,           # stroke
          fillColor = ~pal(town.positivity),
          fillOpacity = 1,
          label = ~text,
          labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "15px", ## could also set "font-size" in 'style' arg
                                      style = list( # add custom CSS
                                        "background-color" = "darkgreen",
                                        "color" = "white" # font color
                                      ))) %>%
 addLegend(
  "bottomright",
  pal = pal_2,
  values = ~town.positivity,
  title = "<b>Test Positivity (%)</b>",
  labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x)  sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  opacity = 1
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!